# Passing data to php script via axios ajax post

Tags: php, axios

I'm try to pass data to a php script via axios but I am not having any sucess
My scripts are below:

**AXIOS SCRIPT**

```
var config = {
   headers: {
     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  }
```

};

```
new Vue({
el:'#app',
data:{
    email:'',
    access:''
},
methods:{
    signin:function(){
        console.log(this.email + ' ' + this.access);
        let url = '../App/testConnection.php';
        axios.post(url,{email:this.email, code:this.access}, config)
      .then((response) =>{
          console.log(response.data);
      })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
        //console.log(this.email + ' ' + this.access);
        //alert(this.email);
    }
```

}
});

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
        $data = $_POST;
        var_dump($data);
```

Comment: URL that you are using is wrong, use with HTTP or https like this: http://yourdomain.com/App/testConnection.php instead of the physical path (let url = '../App/testConnection.php')

Comment: @abrar changing the URL did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url is incorrect. Try another url which is

```
let url = 'domainname.com/App/testConnection.php';
```

Or

```
let url = 'localhost/App/testConnection.php';
```

If you test localy

Comment: Made the change to the URL but still the data is not being passed