# POST params not getting read by $_POST via AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have been trying to post data to my PHP script, **which works fine for POSTMAN, shows the results correctly**. But in while sending the data using AJAX in my html project, the data is not being sent/accepted by the PHP script, hence no show data.

**Possible Problem:** JSON data type is not working for PHP script, since param is not getting read by `$_POST['phone_num']`

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8888/project/my-script.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send('{ "phone_num" : "12345678" }');
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Script:**

```
$request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ( $request_method == 'POST' ){
      echo "This is working!!";
      echo $_GET['phone_num'];
}else {
      echo json_encode('No defined function for this method');
}
```

**Tried:**

- Tried passing the data as `{ "phone_num" : 12345678 }`, not worked
- Followed this link: [Passing data to php script via ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49973312/passing-data-to-php-script-via-axios-ajax-post), not worked out for me

**Result:** I get `This is working!!`, but no phone_num which I passed through this code via AJAX

**Observation:** There is a catch, if we use `$_POST['phone_num']` in place of `$_GET['phone_num']`, then the POSTMAN also doesn't return any data except `This is working!!`.

**Screenshot:**

- POSTMAN:

[image: Postman Screenshot]

- HTML PAGE:

[image: HTML page Screenshot]

Please help where I am going wrong. That'd be great. Thanks.

Comment: _Small Point_ `$request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];` WHY

Comment: To check, if things working fine or not. It won't make a difference, right?

Comment: You send "phone_num" trough a POST request, in PHP you can fetch that variable then with $_POST["phone_num"] instead of $_GET, with the $_get you can read variables from the url

Comment: No wont fix it, but a waste of cpu cycles and memory :)

Comment: `echo $_POST['phone_num'];` because `xhttp.open("POST",.....)`

Comment: Not working @RiggsFolly. also mentioned in my catch

Comment: what you get with var_dump($_POST); ?if it is empty then your javascript is not correct. Also check your console log and network tab of your browser to see wat happends

Comment: @Baracuda078 I got `NULL`

Comment: Change xhttp.send('{ "phone_num" : "12345678" }'); to xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({phone_num" : "12345678"})); maybe that will help

Comment: I did not get anything, same response @Baracuda078, `NULL`. Plus I tried with `var_dump($_POST)`, I got `array(0) { }`

Comment: xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("phone_num=12345678");
Try it with this I tested it and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>this will work try getting data with `file_get_contents('php://input')` instead of using `$_POST`</s>

i tried it with you code and it works

```
$value = file_get_contents('php://input');
$value = json_decode($value);
$phone = $value->{"phone_num"};
echo $phone;
```

**I think this is a better approach**

**JS**

```
const response = fetch('http://localhost:8888/project/my-script.php', {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({phone_num: 12345678}).toString()
  });
```

**PHP**

```
 $request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    if ( $request_method == 'POST' ){
          echo "This is working!!";
          echo($_POST["phone_num"]);
    }else {
          echo json_encode('No defined function for this method');
    }
```

Comment: By this I get `{"phone": "12345678"}`, which I don't want, I want to fetch the data value of `phone` only. Thanks

Comment: i have edited the answer for decoding the json

Comment: One question, why this doesn't work in POSTMAN? It doesn't show up any output, it worked on HTML now. I will mark your answer, just wanted to ask this question.

Comment: @Alok i havnt worked in PHP in long while, i think this is some sort of issue with formatting on the JS side. Working with base `xmlHttp` is a real pain in the ass. You might have better luck if you use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: Thanks Nijeesh, your answer helped me. Thank you so much. I hope people will get benefited with your answer, if that will open again. Hahaha!

Comment: @Alok i have changed the code with something i believe to be a better approach, please let me know if this works for you

Comment: That worked Nijeesh. The catch was it `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` as header. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET`.

I know it is lame to use that. But even with ReactJS also, I am facing the same issue and I resolved it with this.

Comment: Not working Nikhil. Postman works fine, but for HTML, Same output `This is working!!`.

Answer (score -1):

```
xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8888/project/my-script.php", true);
```

In your above url it seems that you are sending a post request

```
$request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ( $request_method == 'POST' ){
      echo "This is working!!";
      echo $_GET['phone_num'];
}else {
      echo json_encode('No defined function for this method');
}
```

And if your php function it seems that you are accessing the variable `phone_num` using the GLOBAL GET array.

Change it to post

```
$_POST['phone_num'];
```

Comment: It doesn't work here. I have mentioned in my CATCH description in my question

Comment: https://github.com/fahadpatel/ajax_form 

check this link I've write this for you @Alok

Comment: @fahad patel Your using JQuery in your code but not loading it in! So this will not work for him, and we are not sure he whant's to use JQuery

Comment: it is obvoius he will linked it.

Comment: @fahad patel You never know here ;)

Comment: @Baracuda078 well I have added the CDN for JQuery :)

Answer (score -1):

use this

> echo $_POST['phone_num'];

Instead of

> echo $_GET['phone_num'];

Comment: I have already told you that it doesn't work for `$_POST['phone_num']`, please see my CATCH in my question